# $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

Tags: php, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

im try to make a fan gate content for my facebook fan page by singed_request. The code work perfectly but i don't want redirect in iframe, i need redirect after the user click LIKE to another page. How i can remove iframe and insert a redirect?

this is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('facebook.php');
$app_id = "id";
$app_secret = "secret";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
function parsePageSignedRequest() { if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {     $encoded_sig = null; $payload = null; list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.',     $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2); $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true)); return     $data; } >return false; } if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {     if($signed_request->page->liked) { echo "<iframe allowtransparency=\"true\"     frameborder=\"0\" SCROLLING=\"YES\" style=\"width: 800px; height: 1000px;\"     src=\"http://onlyimagination.com/dm3theme2\" id=\"any_name\" name=\"anyname\"><iframe>";
} else { echo "<img src=\"http://www.onlyimagination.com/facebook/crazyvideo/img.jpg\"     width=\"582\" height=\"487\">"; } }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if don't have any output before your code

```
if ($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
    if ($signed_request->page->liked) {
        header('Location: http://onlyimagination.com/dm3theme2');
    } else {
        echo "<img src=\"http://www.onlyimagination.com/facebook/crazyvideo/img.jpg\"     width=\"582\" height=\"487\">";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't consider that being me helping you to learn about PHP programming. You could always hire a consultant if you have no interest in learning this stuff your self.

Comment: What I have done in my code is  replacing the output of an iframe with a header call (http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), sending the visitor to a new URL.

Comment: Sorry, I that's to hard to read, update your question. What error do you get?

Comment: you should be carefull with having you app id and app secret here